# Proving a point is on the circumcircle of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, circles

Given that C is the center of the inscribed circle of triangle DEF, A is the center of the circle which is tangent to EF and to the extensions of DE and DF, and G is the midpoint of CA, prove that G is on the circumcircle of triangle DEF.

I've made the circumcircle (it's grey and dotted), but the proof is eluding me. Any hints/advice are helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very well-known theorem in geometry. It is referred to as the "Incenter-Excenter Lemma". We know that the incenter and the excenter of a triangle are collinear with the respective vertex. You can then prove that $\triangle CGF$ is isosceles via angle chase. So, $CG=CF$. Similarly, show that $CE=CG$, and you will be done. Here is the link [Evan Chen's article](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Fact5/Fact5.pdf), which both includes a brief proof and many example problems, showing the power of this lemma. Also see [Osman Nal's video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlYNIAE2j5o&list=PLa8j0YHOYQQIsoK8nRdF2OJxdCiiiFWPT&ab_channel=OsmanNal) on Evan Chen's article.

---

The incenter is the point of concurrency of the interior angle bisectors. Furthermore, usually the $D$-excenter is defined as the intersection of exterior angle bisectors of $\angle E$ and $\angle F$, rather than as the reflection of $C$ (incenter) over $G$ in your diagram. These are useful for angle chasing.